# How do I re-deploy an application in Google app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Could someone please explain how I can re-deploy an application in Google app engine ?
Is there anyway to accomplish this using `appcfg.py`

Comment: how did you deploy it the first time? its the same procedure.

Comment: Deploying is the same procedure.  If you don't change the version, the new one overwrites the old...

Comment: Thanks..Didn't guess that I can re-deploy while earlier instance is running.